# Weird : Eslint raising no-unused-vars for used variables

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

I have this piece of code :

```
for(const physicalEffect of deleteSolution.physicalEffects) {
        const { solutions } = cache.readQueryNoThrow({
          query: solutionsQuery,
          variables: {
            projectId: project.id,
            physicalEffect: physicalEffect.id,
            engineeringArticle: null,
            biologyArticle: null
          }
        })
        solutions && cache.writeQuery({
          query: solutionsQuery,
          variables: {
            projectId: project.id,
            physicalEffect: physicalEffect.id,
            engineeringArticle: null,
            biologyArticle: null
          },
          data: {
            solutions: solutions.filter(({ id }) => id !== deleteSolution.id)
          }
        })
      }
```

Using create-react-app, react-app-rewired and customize-cra, I have the following `.eslintrc` :

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
  }
}
```

And I'm having this warning :

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/pages/project/solution/Editor.js
  Line 60:   'physicalEffect' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
```

Line 60 is referring to the first line of my code sample above. The warning is raised by the `physicalEffect` declaration in the `for ... of` loop.

What the heck is going on ?

Comment: Which is line 60? Is it included in this code?

Comment: @skovy Yes, it's line 1 on my sample.